# Using the Newton-Quotient

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the function $f(x) = |8x^3 − 1|$ isn't differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Now I know that I need to use the newton quotient to prove that the left hand limit is not equal to the right hand limit. That is

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^{-}} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac{1}{2})}{x-\frac{1}{2}}$$

does not equal

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^{+}} \frac{f(x)-f(\frac{1}{2})}{x-\frac{1}{2}}$$

however im struggling with the actual calculation itself and would appreciate some help. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use $f(x)=-(8x^3-1)$ for Left derivative and  $f(x)=8x^3-1$ for right.

Comment: yes i know that much but i can't seem to compute it. normally i would look to factorise say (8x^3 -1) to give (x-1/2) times something but i can't seem to find anything

Answer (score 0):

you have $$8x^3 - 1=(2x-1)(4x^2 + 2x + 1)=3(2x-1) + O((2x-1)^2) $$ the graph of $y = 8x^3 - 1$ has slope $6$ at $x = 1/2.$  the graph of $y = |8x^3 - 1|$ will have a slope $-6$ from the left and $6$ from the right. that it will look like a wedge at $x = 1/2$ so that $|8x^3 - 1|$ has no tangent at $(1/2,0).$ another way of saying this is that $|8x^3-1|$ is not differentiable at $x = 1/2.$